# Creating a physicsBody from a texture out of a texture atlas results in weird proportions

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I use physicsBodies that are made from an image, I put an image file in the Assets.xcassets file and create the spriteNode using the image name as the imageNamed argument, I then use the spriteNodes texture as the texture argument of the physicsBody and the same size value from the spriteNode as the size argument. This works like a charm below 13.0 (13.0 has some issues with this). However, if I try to do this same thing with the same image files but in a Texture Atlas the spriteNode() still looks perfectly fine but the physicsBody is massively out of proportion, I would be able to get them to line up by dividing the width and height of the physicsBody by different values but the fact that I'm gonna have to brute force something means I've probably done something wrong

Image of result when using spriteAtlas, keep in mind the wings aren't part of the spriteNode and the rectangle around the eagle is a different body: [oh no no no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfxNU.png)

How I create physicsBodies:

```swift
func createPigeon(size: CGSize, position: CGPoint) {
        //W/o texture atlas
        sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "pigeonHitBox")
        //with textureAtlas
        sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: gameScene.spriteAtlas.textureNamed("pigeonHitBox"))

        sprite!.size = size
        sprite!.position = position
        sprite!.name = "Pigeon"
        sprite!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: sprite!.texture!, size: size)
        sprite!.zPosition = 1
        sprite!.physicsBody!.isDynamic = true
        defaultCollisions()
        gameScene.addChild(sprite!)
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you may be grabbing the wrong size

Comment: @Knight0fDragon They use the same value. 

```swift
func createPigeon(size: CGSize, position: CGPoint) {
        sprite!.size = size
        sprite!.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: sprite!.texture!, size: size)
    }
```

Comment: Both you and I do not know that.  Asset grabbing is very complex in sprite kit because it tries its best to ensure it is grabbing an asset.  On top of that, how you create your asset matters, and when the asset atlas gets allocated also matters.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ???? I'm passing the same argument for size to both, that's what I meant.

I think what's happening is that when the spriteAtlas is set up it doesn't account for alpha allowing more images to fit so when it applies a size to the texture it appears warped

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that the problem was due to the way SpriteKit overlaps and deletes alpha in order to squeeze more images into one atlas. The only fix I could find for this was putting the images I used for hitboxes into the Assets.xcassets file and making sure the animation action had resize set to false.

I get why this is done but this has just resulted in me not being able to put a good 13 images inside a textureAtlas, there should be an option to not axe alpha

Comment: There's a bug in either iOS 13 or Xcode 11 that affects physics bodies created from textures. It's not just a texture atlas issue.

Comment: @0x141E yeah, I'm using 12.2 due to 13.0 breaking texture created physicsBodies, I made a bug report to apple on feedback assistant regarding that a few weeks ago but so far it's been ignored and had the amount of similar reports changed to "less than 10" but so far that's it. Does the issue persist in 13.1 and above? (I haven't updated Xcode yet)

Comment: Yes, 13.1.2 has the issue as well.

Comment: @0x141E darn, they really need to fix that

Comment: 13.1.3 too, unfortunately

Comment: Looks like Apple fixed the problem in 13.2